# Storing Invoices in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I wanted to get some advice on how to go about storing invoice data in a mysql database.

My first understanding would be to have two tables..

**Invoices** & **Invoice_rows**..

**Invoices** would hold FK to Client ID, invoice number, invoice date, paid or unpaid flag

**Invoice_rows** would hold all the items to invoice, FK to invoices, description, price, tax

Only thing is after the invoice is created it might need to be updated.. spelling mistake, extra item needed to be added etc. So for this is i will first need to query to get all of the rows, then I will need to execute multiple updates to all the rows every time a change is made.

Would storing all the rows as JSON in a text field for each individual invoice in the single **invoices** table work well or cause more of a problem? the fact that all rows will need to be updated regardless if there was only a change to one row upon save makes no difference just converting it to json and replacing the text field with the new JSON surely? The JSON wouldn't need to be searchable either as it's the client that will be searched and will list all of their invoices based upon their ID.

Any recommendation to make this efficient and easy to work with is most appreciated!

Comment: Why would you need to update all the rows when there's a spelling mistake?  Just find the row that needs to be updated and update that one.

Comment: But lets say you have all the rows present and a save button.. you can amend anything to do with the invoice in one go by hitting a save button how do i determine what has and has not been changed.. I want to offer that flexibility to my users without providing a save button to every single row or without using AJAX

Comment: AJAX might be better: it depends.  You could use an on change handler with javascript to the inputs, and then when they hit save, only send the changed info.

Comment: Could do! I already have on keyup so all the tax and pricing gets updated as they type.. I'm just trying to think of efficiency. I could go with breaking everything down into multiple tables and doing all sorts of fancy things in the background to keep my queries down. it's just if i don't have to over complicate i wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of the changes in the front end and call your AJAX method when they're done.  The method should take the invoice number and any updated rows including the PKs.

Do *NOT* store JSON in the database.  That would be a truly awful thing.  JSON is just a useful mechanism for transit and your choice of UI.  It is *not* your data but a temporary transformation of it.

Comment: Sounds like the best option. Thank you for the second opinion!